# How i fix "TypeError: prop_types__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.object.keys is not a function" for react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try to render my components with the code I wrote in the scrollService, I get this error how can I fix it?

```
  41 |     }
  42 | }
  43 | checkCurrentScreenUnderViewport = (event)=>{
> 44 |     if(!event || object.keys(event).length < 1)
     | ^  45 |     return;
  46 |     for(let screen of TOTAL_SCREENS){
  47 |         let screenFromDom = document.getElementById(screen.screen_name);
```

Error Message : TypeError: prop_types__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.object.keys is not a function

Comment: You need to capitalize it. `Object.keys`, not `object.keys`

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I didn't pay attention